# Axios post-request doesn't send complete object

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I need to send an object including a base64-encoded image to an API-endpoint in TS. I use this code to convert a file to Base64 and attach it to an object:

```
const file = values.beleg1;
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = async function () {
                    const result = reader.result.toString().split(',')[1];
                    await valuesObj.push({ name: 'base64Image', value: result });

                };
                reader.onerror = function (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                };
```

If I then log the object 'valuesObj' it does show that the base64-object is attached to the main-object.
[image: Screenshot of the logged object]

However when I then I then use this object in the request like in the code below it is not shown in the payload when looking at the network-request

```
axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/createPDF',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                responseType: 'blob',
                data: valuesObj,
            })
                .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
                    setLoadingText('');
                    const blob: Blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    const objectUrl: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    window.open(objectUrl);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

[image: Screenshot of the network-payload]

What is the reason for this? Does it have anything to do with the length/size of the string? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Where lives your valuesObj ??

Comment: It is instantiated at the very top with `const valuesObj: { name: string; value: string; }[] = [];` so it should definitely be in scope

Comment: I know why, it's because of your async function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is the reader hasn't finished reading before the Axios call proceeds. The reader executes asynchronously. Thus, the order of operations often ends up something like this:

1. Start the read operation.
2. Attach event handler `onloaded`.
3. Start the Axios request, which is probably sent immediately at this point.
4. Complete the read operation.
5. Complete the Axios request.

Because you aren't waiting for the load event to finish before sending the Axios request, the request does not include the new data. You need to make sure the load event is finished and the data is pushed onto your array before you proceed with the Axios call.

```
try {
    const file = values.beleg1;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    // construct a promise that will resolve once loading is complete,
    //   and then wait for it, so that we don't make the axios call until
    //   after the loading is done.
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onload = function () {
            const result = reader.result.toString().split(',')[1];
            valuesObj.push({ name: 'base64Image', value: result });
            // notify that the promise has completed its work
            resolve();
        };

        reader.onerror = function () {
            // notify that the promise failed and pass along the error object
            reject(reader.error);
        };
    });

    // I picked any since I don't want to define out the full type, but you probably should
    const response: any = await axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/createPDF',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: valuesObj,
    });

    setLoadingText('');
    const blob: Blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const objectUrl: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
} catch (error) {
    // all errors during the processing are caught in one place
    console.log('Error: ', error);
}
```

Note that I put everything in async/await style, except the required `Promise` object, and I have a single try-catch block. If you want to process errors at a higher level of granularity, split it into multiple try-catch blocks.

When we make sure to await every asynchronous action, we ensure that we don't start the next one until we are done with the previous, so everything is done in order.

Comment: Very good answer concerning style and clearness so you got my vote, but still not everyone is as gifted as you in written speech and/or programming and I think that a solution still stays valuable independent of it's elegance but of course your response should be valued higher, point being that it's simply a bad social style to tackle someone who aims to help in such a way like you did !

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem seems to be that your async axios request gets the value of your valuesObj, before onload actually adds your new record.

Sorry forgot a solution ^^

Either you put your axios request directly into the pipe...

```
reader.onload = 
        (async function () {
            const result = reader.result.toString().split(',')[1]
            await valuesObj.push({ name: 'base64Image', value: result})
            return valuesObj
        })
        .then( 
            data =>
            axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/createPDF',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                responseType: 'blob',
                data,
            })
            .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
                setLoadingText('')
                const blob: Blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
                const objectUrl: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                window.open(objectUrl)
            })
            .catch(console.log))
        )

})
```

or you create another async function which you can call from your onload or from another async fn, which awaits both async events.

Comment: Sadly even deleting the `async` doesn't help. I did noticed that when moving the entire request into the onload-method it does seem to work, however I don't think making such deeply nested code is the correct solution. Do you have any idea what other method I could use to solve this?

Comment: Yes I agree about the nesting

Comment: Your solution did work and I'm gonna use it as a starting-point to see how I can work from here with this. Thank you for your help

Comment: I ' m glad I could help I did edit my version a little bit just some secs ago...should work this way too.

But it's true that it's still not optimal, but async await is always a mess ! Less than the old Promises though!

Comment: Create a promise and resolve it inside of your onload event. Or you can use the promisify library to do this for you.

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound you don't need that initial async function and you certainly don't need to await push(), which is not an async function. This actually really poorly constructed.

Comment: @siride
First I just worked with what he had until now and out of an aducational perspective that makes way more sense than rewriting everything. 
Second Promises are old and depreceated ! And third an unconstructive comment like yours doesn't help anybody !

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound Promise are most definitely not deprecated. That's how async await works! And you can't avoid using them explicitly in some cases such as this one. I'm sorry to call you out but if you are going to post an answer it should be good. This site is not a participation exercise.

Comment: @siride
I haven't seen you posting an answer yet !
If you have a significantly better one, then post it ! I will even upvote if it's good.

Comment: Once I get to my computer I will.

Comment: I have created an answer.

Comment: Great answer *thumbsup*